# Gerund or Infinitive after an adjective

Tags: grammar, gerund-vs-infinitive

I came across the following test exercise on Gerunds and Infinitives.

> The Oscar-winning actor avoids talking to his fans and refuses to give
> his autograph. <more context>. Doesn't he seem way too shy
> **being/to be** an actor?

I'm confused by the choice. In my option both options are fine; the latter is grammatically correct but the former conveys the meaning better.

- Doesn't he seem way too shy **being** an actor?
  He is an actor and I'm surprised he is shy.
- Doesn't he seem way too shy **to be** an actor?
  He is shy and I'm surprised he is an actor.

Does my understanding make sense?

Comment: It's not "following an adjective" that's involved. It's a special negative construction governed by _too_, which requires an infinitive clause.  Using a gerund is ungrammatical. Gerunds can be used for other purposes, but that requires special intonation, which requires special punctuation in writing.

Comment: Which is what @linguisticturn says in his answer. The infinitival complement clause is licensed by the "too" that modifies the adjective "shy".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your understanding does make sense. However, the sentence with the gerund requires a comma:

[1]  *Doesn't he seem way too shy**,** being an actor?*

The part after the comma is a **supplement,** not integrated into the syntactical structure of the sentence. The meaning is, 'Given that he is an actor, I would expect him to not be so shy'.

On the other hand, the sentence

[2]  *Doesn't he seem way too shy to be an actor?*

has the meaning 'Given that he is so shy, I am surprised that he is an actor'.

As best as I can tell, there are only a few adjectives that can enter into a construction of the form *too* + ADJ + *being* + PC (where PC stands for 'predicative complement') with no comma between the adjective and *being*. *Shy* is not one of them, but here are some that are:

*He was too **busy** being successful/a lawyer.*
*He was too **happy** being drunk/a father.*
*He was too **sad** being [alone in their own home]/a refugee.*
*He was too **comfortable** being naked/a permanent guest.*

Comment: Perfect explanation! Thank you

Comment: 'too [adj] to be ...' means '[adj] to such an extent that one can not be ...'. With your other examples, there is usually an implied 'to be' or other to-infinitive: 'He was too busy being a lawyer to think of starting a family'. I suppose 'He was too sad being alone in their own home' is more realistically followed by say 'for him to stay there very long' (or perhaps 'to not be offered a new home living with his children').

Answer (score 0):

> Doesn't he seem way too shy being an actor?
> He is an actor and I'm surprised he is shy.
>
> Doesn't he seem way too shy to be an actor?
> He is shy and I'm surprised he is an actor.
>
> Does my understanding make sense?

No, and it is incorrect.

The English verb has two major forms: the simple: "I go" and the continuous "I am going."

This is true of stative verbs, and participles and infinitives also. "I am stupid" = My over-all state can be described as "stupid" - I am being stupid = I am currently in a state of stupidity.

This also applies to all other "-ing" forms including the gerund and verbal noun.

*Doesn't he seem way too shy being an actor?* = Doesn't he seem way too shy **while he is in the process of being** an actor?

*Doesn't he seem way too shy to be an actor?* = Doesn't he seem way too shy **in order** to be an actor? = Doesn't he seem way too shy **[in order] to carry out the complete job of an actor?**

See also ["they had renovated" vs "had been renovating"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/546439/how-can-i-understand-the-sentence-1b/546441#546441)

Comment: The last bit won't work. Clauses with "in order" are purpose adjuncts, but there's no sense in which we can say here that there is a purpose to his shyness.

Comment: @BillJ You may have misunderstood or too prescriptive. You can read it as "in order for him to be an actor" or "if he is an actor"  or the archaic "[in order] that he be an actor"

Comment: Perhaps it's an expression that is only found in some dialects. I can't say that I've ever used it with that meaning.

Comment: How about "for the purpose of his being an actor"?

Answer (score 0):

"Doesn't he seem way too shy to be an actor?" means "Doesn't he seem to be more shy than is compatible with being an actor?" "Too X to Y" means "So much X that Y is not possible", e.g. "Too heavy to lift", "Too far to walk".